# Copy paste to PARI/GP

Tags: pari-gp

I have a text in my notebook and I'd like to copy it to PARI/GP. The text is a little bit long, but I'm not sure if I'm not getting it just because of that. I've tried CTRL C + CTRL V and Copy-Paste and none of them worked. Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can save your program to file `app.gp` and just run it in PARI/GP via command like `gp -q app.gp`.

Comment: It probably depends on operating system. In windows right mouse click does paste. (copy is selecting with mouse). There are also Mark and Paste commands in the Edit sub-menu. Cannot speak for Linux. (but since you mention ctrl c that sounds like windows). On web version (https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/gp.html) you can just paste into blue box using ctrl c + ctrl v.

Answer (score 1):

I am using gp with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and to perform paste of one or more lines into the gp session shift ctrl v works. To copy from a gp session I highlight text and copy using shift ctrl c.